# How would it possible to Andromeda collide with Milky way?

Tags: galaxy, collision

If galaxies are moving away from each other how is it possible to Andromeda collide with Milky Way?

Comment: Another good match is [In km/h, what actually is the “speed” of Andromeda away from us: cosmologically?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18609)

Comment: Prof Rob has some relevant info (including a diagram) here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/574385/123208